# **Prove that if all the principal normals of a curve pass through a fixed point, the curve is either a circular arc or a whole circle.**

Tags: differential-geometry

**Prove that if all the principal normals of a curve pass through a fixed point, the curve is either a circular arc or a whole circle.**

I determined that I would need to prove that torsion was zero and that the curve lived in a sphere. I started by trying to prove torsion was zero.

Let $C$ be the fixed point (vector). Then there exists some $u(s)$ so that:

$C = x(s) + u(s)N(s)$, where $N$ is the normal vector.

From there, I took the derivative of each side of the equation with respect to s to get:

$0 = T + u'(s)N + u(s)(-\kappa T-\tau B)$, where $T$ is the tangent vector and $B$ is the binormal vector.

Rewrite: $(1-u(s)\kappa)T+u'(s)N-u(s)\tau B = 0$

And then I'm kind of stuck. I could dot the whole equation with $B$ and that would at least let me get $\tau$ by itself and play around with proving either $\tau = 0$ or $\lVert B\rVert ^2 = 0$. But I did not think $\lVert B\rVert ^2 = 0$ when thinking about it.

I've seen some references online about $(T,N,B)$ being orthonormal, but we have not discussed that in class at all so I do not think I should replicate that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that $(T,N,B)$ are linearly independent? If so, you know that the three coefficients in the equation you got are all zero, which gives you a  lot of information.

Comment: You've seen the Frenet-Serret formulas (e.g., $N' = - \kappa T - \tau B$) but not the fact that the Frenet trihedron $\{T, N, B\}$ is orthonormal...?